# Can error correction codes constitute an entertaining game?

Tags: algorithm

Whenever I play Sudoko, I see the finished puzzle as an overspecified version of the original input. Like 8b/10b, Reed-Solomon codes, turbo codes, or low-density parity-check codes. With ECC the computer has to solve a puzzle to produce the correct data, and with Sudoku the human has to solve a puzzle to produce 81 digits *of fun*.

Do you think any of these ECC codes would make a good pencil and paper game? (8b/10b -- the home version!)

Is there a good way to represent data as Sudoku puzzles to make the most ridiculous ECC available?

Comment: This isn't really programming related

Comment: Whatever you're smoking, can you please send me a link so I can buy some? :-)

Comment: @Terrapin: It's 2 algorithm design questions. I could rewrite it as (a) design an ECC scheme that can be solved in about 25 minutes on paper, and (b) design a scheme to encode data in a Sudoku puzzle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Representing arbitrary data as a sudoku puzzle is not particularly feasible as the total number of sudoku grids (and thus, the number of distinct pieces of information that could be represented by a puzzle) is far too low (approx 6E21) to encode a significant amount of data (more than about 9 bytes).

Add to this the computational difficulty of producing a non-ambiguous puzzle for a given solution, and the widely varying data density of the optimal puzzle for different solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at the overspecification in the final result is to consider the original state as the result of a compression algorithm.

[Nonograms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonogram) are another example of a very information-sparse result being represented in the form of an information-dense puzzle.